# X12 Data Type R with Biztalk 2013

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2013, x12

I don't understand how the X12 data type R works. I have a 4010 x12 210 schema with a L102 field that accepts ***X12_R (SimpleType)***.

What do I tell customers this field accepts?

I thought it would be an R2 but if they send the value **0.10**, it will error out. Biztalk will accept values like **.10** or **65.10**.

Is this considered just R without the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X12 R is just any Real number.

However, by default, leading and trailing 0's are not accepted so if your Trading Partner has to send values like 0.10, you must set the Leading and Trailing Spaces and Zeroes rule to Allow or Trim on the Validation section of the THEM->YOU tab of the Agreement.

However, it better to tell them to not send unnecessary characters.

There's no such thing as R2 (Rx), decimal notation is required.  There is Nx where the x is the number of implied decimal places.

Comment: Thanks Johns-305! This has cleared a lot for me... I was playing in the validation section under transactions settings in the THEM>YOU tab, and every time I set the Leading and Trailing Spaces and Zeroes rule to allow or trim, it would bug out and create an empty new row with that setting. My row with the my X12 document selected would stay on NotAllowed. The only bypass I could use changing the fallback settings, but even so, I will use your advice and tell them to not send unnecessary characters.

Comment: Yes, the lists on the Validation and Envelope sections can seem a bit flakey.  One thing to not, the Default should always be it's own row, then you create other rows to override that by document type.